# How to disable panning in Jquery flot when there is no further data?

Tags: jquery, flot

How to disable panning in Jquery flot when there is no further data ?

I am currently using plot.pan({ left: -100 }); and plot.pan({ left: 100 }); on left arrow
click and right arrow click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've handeled panning limitation by setting the `panRange` option every time the plot's data values change. This way you don't need any other changes, the navigation plugin will do the rest.

```
plot.getOptions().xaxis.panRange =
  [plot.getAxes().xaxis.datamin, plot.getAxes().xaxis.datamax];
plot.getOptions().yaxis.panRange =
  [plot.getAxes().yaxis.datamin, plot.getAxes().yaxis.datamax];
```

Answer (score 1):

this work for me:

```
axis = plot.getAxes();
axis.xaxis.options.panRange = [axis.xaxis.datamin, axis.xaxis.datamax];

// for redraw

plot.setupGrid();
plot.draw();
```